# Question about compatibility of High Sierra (on MBP 2017) w Photoshop Elements 2018

Tags: high-sierra, adobe-photoshop

Specifically: Are there certain things I should do on my end (MacBook Pro 2017, High Sierra) so as to avoid crashing Photoshop Elements 2018? Not having a decent photo software on my MBP is driving me crazy and Gimp just doesn't do it for me (subscribing to Photoshop isn't worth it).

I've read tons of reviews. For every 5-star glowing review, there is a damning one. PE2018 should be the same upon delivery (download or disc), right? The variable here is the computer environment--which is why I am posting my question here and not on Amazon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether your concern is around the fact you're running macOS High Sierra or that you're using a 2017 MacBook Pro?

What I can tell you is that I've seen Photoshop Elements 2018 work just fine on Macs running macOS High Sierra. There really shouldn't be any issues, although everyone's system is different because of the software they have installed and external hardware that may be connected.

However, just in case you weren't aware, you can [download a trial](https://www.adobe.com/products/elements-family/photoshop-elements/download-trial/try.html?promoid=K42KVY19&mv=other) of Photoshop Elements 2018 to try it out first. I'd do that if you still have any concerns.

Comment: I am taking your advice to try it out first-will report back. Reason I hadn't done it: Adobe tends to install a lot of system files that are hard to get rid of. My initial concern was mostly High Sierra, but also whether there is any pattern to PE2018 crashing due to other existing software on a recent MBP.

Comment: Follow up: I installed a trial version of PE2018-it's working flawlessly. Granted, this is a new computer with no existing Adobe software (aside from Acrobat Reader). At one point during the downloading process, I was asked whether I had older versions of the software installed (This was unrelated to getting the "update" version.) So those with older PE versions on their laptop may want to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share your experiences. I'm sure this will help others! :)

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop and Illustrator 2018 CC have never once crashed for me on High Sierra on a 2016 MBP i7 with 4gb radeon 460 even when running a lot of different applications while having 10 or so open files in Photoshop, if that's helpful.

Comment: Actually, yes, even though you are talking about Adobe CC. If PE2018 doesn't work well, I'll resort to CC. For what I do, PE is adequate for now, which is why I am going to try PE first.